# react native navigation- Cannot get property 'RNNKotlinVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Post-installation of react-native navigation when you run `npx react-native run-android`
You get errors like

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/ajayk/code/mine/gramin/judo/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-navigation'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.
```

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-navigation'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/ajayk/code/mine/gramin/judo/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/build.gradle' line: 15
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-navigation'.

> Cannot get property 'RNNKotlinVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above issue, you need to run `npx rnn-link` and then run `npx react-native run-android`